# Trigger that logs changes on every INSERT, DELETE

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

I tried create a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER DataTrigger ON Data AFTER INSERT , DELETE
AS
BEGIN
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Inserted)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[AuditTrail]
       ([ActionType]
       ,[TableName]
       ,[Name]
       ,[Time])

('INSERT'   //Incorrect syntax near 'INSERT'
    ,'Data' 
    ,SELECT col1 FROM Inserted
    ,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  //Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')
END
```

but it keep saying that I have thoes errors, can somebody show me where I did wrong?

P/S: what is the best way to detect an update? 
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER DataTrigger ON Data AFTER INSERT , DELETE
AS
BEGIN    
  INSERT INTO [dbo].[AuditTrail]
       ([ActionType]
       ,[TableName]
       ,[Name]
       ,[Time])
  SELECT 'INSERT'  
    ,'Data' 
    ,col1
    ,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
  FROM Inserted

END
```

Just for clarification.

Your query, if syntatically correct would have failed if more than one row was inserted, the version above allows for multiple inserts.

The `IF EXISTS` was redundant, which is why it was removed, if there are no rows there will be no insert into your audit table.

If you want to audit `DELETE` you'll need a similar statement again, but using the `Deleted` table rather than `Inserted`

To audit `UPDATE`, create a new trigger, for each updated row you get an entry in `Inserted` with the new updates and an entry in `Deleted` with the old data, you can join these if you want to track old and new.

Comment: we don't need the IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Inserted) statement, do we?

Answer (score 3):

```
CREATE TRIGGER DataTrigger ON Data AFTER INSERT , DELETE
AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO [dbo].[AuditTrail]
       ([ActionType]
       ,[TableName]
       ,[Name]
       ,[Time])
SELECT 'INSERT', 'Data', col1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP FROM Inserted

END
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure what you are trying to accomplish here so I have just corrected the syntax to get it to work, but it should help.  I have also tried to handle the deleted case as well

```
CREATE TRIGGER DataTrigger 

ON Data 

AFTER INSERT , DELETE 
AS
BEGIN


    INSERT INTO [dbo].[AuditTrail]([ActionType],       
                                             [TableName],       
                                             [Name],       
                                             [Time])
    SELECT 'INSERT','Data', col1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    FROM Inserted


    INSERT INTO [dbo].[AuditTrail]([ActionType],       
                                             [TableName],       
                                             [Name],       
                                             [Time])
    SELECT 'DELETE','Data', col1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    FROM Deleted

END
```